# My paddles move by opposite keys the left paddle moves with arrows while the right paddle moves with wsad. How can I fix that?

Tags: python, pygame, collision

Im replicating a basic pong game and my paddles are opposite. My left paddle moves with the arrows while the right paddle moves with wsad, so when you play the players play they have to move the opposite paddle that they are on the side of. Also, I'm trying to make the ball come back when its off the screen and I was playing around with it and now there's collision with the wall as well as the paddle causing it to be a never ending game instead of rounded pong.

```
# import the necessary modules
import pygame
import sys
import time

#initialize pygame
pygame.init()
screenSize=(700,500)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((screenSize), 0)

# set the caption for the screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Meryem's Pong Game")

# define colours you will be using
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)

# set the size for the surface (screen)
screen_h = screen.get_height()
screen_w = screen.get_width()
cx = int(screen_w/2)
cy = int(screen_h/2)

#initialize variables for player
#variables for first rectangle
R1x = 660
R1y = 300
R1w = 10
R1h = 132

R1dx = 0
R1dy = 0
R1_score = 0

#variables for second rectangle
R2x = 10
R2y = 2
R2w = 10
R2h = 132

R2dx = 0
R2dy = 0
R2_score = 0

#ball variables
bx = cx
by = cy
dby = 3
dbx = 3
br = 5
cy =  screen.get_height()/2
cx =  screen.get_width()/2

# variable for scores
R1_score = 0
R2_score = 0

playerRect = pygame.Rect(R2x,R2y,R2w, R2h)
playerRect2 = pygame.Rect(R1x,R1y,R1w, R1h)
ballRect = pygame.Rect (cx,cy,30,30)

#speed
speed = 3

fontsize = 50
fontScore = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 50)
fontScore = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 50)

R1Score = fontScore.render(str(R1_score), True, (WHITE))
R2Score = fontScore.render(str(R2_score), True, (WHITE))

# speed of object "clock"
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

FPS_easy = 30 # set frames per second for easy level
FPS_medium = 80 # set frames per second for medium level
FPS_progressive = 100 # set frames per second for progressive level

# set main loop to True so it will run
main = True
# main loop
while main:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # check for any events (i.e key press, mouse click etc.)
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT: # check to see if it was "x" at top right of screen
            main = False         # set the "main" variable to False to exit while loop
        if event.type ==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                R1dx = 0
                R1dy = -speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                R1dx = 0
                R1dy = speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                R2dx = 0
                R2dy = -speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                R2dx = 0
                R2dy = speed
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                R1dx = 0
                R1dy = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                R2dx = 0
                R2dy = 0

    playerRect.y = playerRect.y + R1dy
    playerRect2.y = playerRect2.y + R2dy
    ballRect.move_ip(dbx,dby)


    #collision of ball
    if ballRect.top <= 0:
        dby = -dby
    if ballRect.bottom >= screen_h:
        dby = -dby

    if ballRect.left <= 0:
        dbx = -dbx
    if ballRect.right >= screen_w:
        dbx = -dbx

    if ballRect.colliderect(playerRect2):
        dbx = -dbx
    if ballRect.colliderect(playerRect):
        dbx = -dbx

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # draw the shapes, in this case the blue rectangles
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE,(playerRect),0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE,(playerRect2),0)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED,ballRect.center,br,0)
    screen.blit(R1Score, (280,10))
    screen.blit(R2Score, (400,10))

    # we are using .flip() here,  it basically works the same as .update()
    # we will discuss this more in class (you can use either one)
    pygame.display.flip()

# quit pygame and exit the program (i.e. close everything down)
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: what do you want us to help you with

Answer (score 0):

fixed your issues:

```
# import the necessary modules
import pygame
import sys
import time

#initialize pygame
pygame.init()
screenSize=(700,500)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((screenSize), 0)

# set the caption for the screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Meryem's Pong Game")

# define colours you will be using
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)

# set the size for the surface (screen)
screen_h = screen.get_height()
screen_w = screen.get_width()
cx = int(screen_w/2)
cy = int(screen_h/2)

#initialize variables for player
#variables for first rectangle
R1x = 660
R1y = 300
R1w = 10
R1h = 132

R1dx = 0
R1dy = 0
R1_score = 0

#variables for second rectangle
R2x = 10
R2y = 2
R2w = 10
R2h = 132

R2dx = 0
R2dy = 0
R2_score = 0

#ball variables
bx = cx
by = cy
dby = 1
dbx = 1
br = 5
cy =  screen.get_height()/2
cx =  screen.get_width()/2

# variable for scores
R1_score = 0
R2_score = 0

playerRect = pygame.Rect(R2x,R2y,R2w, R2h)
playerRect2 = pygame.Rect(R1x,R1y,R1w, R1h)
ballRect = pygame.Rect (cx,cy,30,30)

#speed
speed = 3

fontsize = 50
fontScore = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 50)
fontScore = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 50)

R1Score = fontScore.render(str(R1_score), True, (WHITE))
R2Score = fontScore.render(str(R2_score), True, (WHITE))

# speed of object "clock"
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

FPS_easy = 30 # set frames per second for easy level
FPS_medium = 80 # set frames per second for medium level
FPS_progressive = 100 # set frames per second for progressive level

# set main loop to True so it will run
main = True
# main loop
while main:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # check for any events (i.e key press, mouse click etc.)
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT: # check to see if it was "x" at top right of screen
            main = False         # set the "main" variable to False to exit while loop
        if event.type ==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                R2dx = 0
                R2dy = -speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                R2dx = 0
                R2dy = speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                R1dx = 0
                R1dy = -speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                R1dx = 0
                R1dy = speed
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                R2dx = 0
                R2dy = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                R1dx = 0
                R1dy = 0

    playerRect.y = playerRect.y + R1dy
    playerRect2.y = playerRect2.y + R2dy
    ballRect.move_ip(dbx,dby)


    #collision of ball
    if ballRect.top <= 0:
        dby = -dby
    if ballRect.bottom >= screen_h:
        dby = -dby

    if ballRect.left <= 0:
        dbx = -dbx
    if ballRect.right >= screen_w:
        dbx = -dbx

    if ballRect.colliderect(playerRect2):
        dbx = -dbx
    if ballRect.colliderect(playerRect):
        dbx = -dbx

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # draw the shapes, in this case the blue rectangles
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE,(playerRect),0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE,(playerRect2),0)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED,ballRect.center,br,0)
    screen.blit(R1Score, (280,10))
    screen.blit(R2Score, (400,10))

    # we are using .flip() here,  it basically works the same as .update()
    # we will discuss this more in class (you can use either one)
    time.sleep(0.005)
    pygame.display.flip()

# quit pygame and exit the program (i.e. close everything down)
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

must say the code you gave isn't very pretty

Answer (score 0):

You have confused `R1x`, `R1y`, `R1w`, `R1h` and `R2x`, `R2y`, `R2w`, `R2h` when you create the `pygame.Rect` objects `playerRect` respectively `playerRect2`

<s>`playerRect = pygame.Rect(R2x,R2y,R2w, R2h)`</s>
<s>`playerRect2 = pygame.Rect(R1x,R1y,R1w, R1h)`</s>

```py
playerRect = pygame.Rect(R1x, R1y, R1w, R1h)
playerRect2 = pygame.Rect(R2x, R2y, R2w, R2h)
```